# LSN mentioned in Backup is missing in Backupset

Tags: sql-server-2012, backup, restore, transaction-log

I was testing some restore scenario for one of my requirement.
SO while i was restoring i got the below error.
`--Msg 4305, Level 16, State 1, Line 79
--The log in this backup set begins at LSN 38000000116400001, which is too recent to apply to the database. 
--An earlier log backup that includes LSN 38000000116100001 can be restored.`

So i checked the `backupset` table to find the missing log backup.
But i couldn't find that LSN in the results.

[image]

I was testing a scenario that is why the full backups are taken every 15 minutes and tlog backup schedules every 5 minutes.
I notice that Full backup and Tlog backup occurs at the same time every 15 minutes.Does that create any issue while restoring.?

Also the restore scenario i am trying is as below:
I start with a full backup  restore,then i restore all tlog backups and i skip full backups which occurred in between.?
Please suggest if there is any issues in that?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft  So even if it in between First and Last LSN thats okay.Understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But i couldn't find that LSN in the results.

The tran log backup taken at 09:00 contains the lsn 38000000116100001.

> Full backup and Tlog backup occurs at the same time every 15 minutes.Does that create any issue while restoring.?

No. Full backups never affect the log chain.

> I start with a full backup restore,then i restore all tlog backups and i skip full backups which occurred in between.?

Yes that is correct.

Comment: I did restore the tran log taken at 09:00 ,but now i have to find out why i got that error.